# Is there any constraint to specify the access specifier of members of a class when we have specified access specifier of the class?

Tags: c#, oop

Suppose that we have a class named class1.

The class1 has several properties and methods and we have decided to specify the access specifier of class1 as internal.

Now, can we set the access specifier of class1 methods as public?

Comment: Yes we can do it. You can try it yourself. I think you want to ask...why? Correct your question in that case.

Answer (score 7):

For your specific question, Class 1 which is declared as internal can have a public method.

Why?

Look at [Jon Skeets explanation](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/226592-internal-class-public-members):

> You can certainly mark a class as
>   internal, but that's different from
>   making its public members internal.
>   For instance, suppose you have a class
>   which implements a public interface.
>   Even though the class may be internal,
>   an instance may still "get out of the
>   assembly" by being returned from a
>   member in another (public) class. That
>   instance would have to be referenced
>   by the interface it implements rather
>   than the class name itself (as the
>   class isn't known to the outside
>   assembly) but the public methods can
>   still be called.
>
> If the public methods aren't
>   implementing any interfaces, I suspect
>   it would only make a difference in a
>   very few reflection cases which you
>   may not care about.

*community wiki - as credit should go to Jon Skeet*

Answer (score 1):

By rule access specifiers on methods and properties can not be more more accessible than that of the class containing it.

But I've tried this:

```
internal class Test
{
    public string Testing{get;set;}
}
```

and **it compiles** without any exception! I think **it is okay** as the class **Test will not be accessible outside the <strike>namespace</strike> assembly** we have declared so public property will not make any difference.

This does not works:

```
private class Test
{
    public string Testing{get;set;}
    internal string TestingAgain{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: The second example is perfectly correct as well... And namespaces have nothing to do with accessibility. The `internal` modifier restricts access to the **assembly** where the class is declared

Comment: @TheVillageldiot:
Well, It's true as you said: "it is okay as the class Test will not be accessible outside the namespace we have declared so public property will not make any difference. "

But what about nested classes? for instance we have a class (class1)
which has been declared as internal with public methods/properties.

Also, we have a second class (class2) which has a property of type class1.  class1 and class2 are both in an assembly and class2's access specifier is public. can we see the class1 out of the assembly it was there?

Comment: Accessibility has **nothing** to do with namespaces; `internal` relates to the *assembly*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set `public` on members of `internal`/`private`/etc types.

As other replies have noted, external code won't be able to see the properties unless it can see the type - but there are lots of nuances:

- if the member is on an interface it will be (essentially) part of the public API
- the member might be a public override of a virtual/abstract member - in which case it *will* truly be publicly visible, but via the base-class (again, similar to interfaces)

But there is a lot of other code in the framework that uses *reflection* and demands public accessibility:

- data binding usually works on the public properties
- security checks for partial-trust can be fussy about public members
- serialization (for example `XmlSerializer`) may want public members
- etc

So there are still lots of reasons to think about `public` rather than just `internal`, even if your code is only referenced by the local assembly.